# Animate layout size change

Tags: android, animation

I have an activity like below screen.

[image: Activity1]

View 1 have width and height as match_parent respectively. View 2 have width match_parent and fixed (200 dp) height.

On a button click I change the visibility (from visible to gone) of View 2. As soon as I hide View 2, View 1 comes in full screen instantly or with a jerk. I want the View 1 to gradually expand to full screen with animation instead of instantly.

How can I animate this layout size change?

Answer (score 2):

You can set [`android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:animateLayoutChanges) on the parent layout. This works from API 11 and onward.

Comment: Thanks. your solution works. However, I have one more question. Suppose View1 and View2 are not views but Fragments. So now at the top is Fragment1 and below it is Fragment2. Now whenever Fragment2 changes size or hides then I want Fragment1 to come on full screen with animation. I tried setting android:animateLayoutChanges="true" on the parent layout of the two FrameLayouts which contains these Fragments but it didn't solved the problem. Please help me out with this new scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use scale animation for view1 and fade out for view2  and then use Animatorset to run both at the same time. For example for a simple scale animation

```
ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(fXscale, toXscale,    fYscale, tYscale, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);//fix to fit your needs.
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The question relates to resizing, which is not the same thing as scaling. I'd delete this before it gets down-voted into oblivion.

Comment: @PaulBurke " I want the View 1 to gradually expand to full screen with animation instead of instantly" what does above line in question suggest ?